# Need to construct an async database object as a property of a parent object

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, constructor, mongoose

I have a `User` object which in its constructor function creates a mongoose database object.

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Data');
var db = mongoose.connection;

UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    salt: String,
    hash: String,
});
UserDB = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

function User(id) {
    var self = this;
    if (id)
        UserDB.findById(id, function(err, user) { // async
            if (!err && user)
                self.db = user;
        });
}
```

But then when I create a user object, its `UserDB` isn't created right away since it's an async database call..

```
user = new User('53179fd401d540b8c5000001');

if (user.db)
    console.log('fail '+user.db.id); // fails because !user.db yet
else
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (user.db)
            console.log('pass '+user.db.id); // only now it works
    }, 1000);
```

What could I do so that either the constructor does not return unless DB object has been created, or something else that doesn't make me do the unreliable setTimeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possibilities you can prevent this.

The fact is, that your db gets instantiated async like you said correctly.

V1: You can pass a callback into users constructor param.

```
function User(id, ready) {
    var self = this;
    if (id)
        UserDB.findById(id, function(err, user) { // async
            if (!err && user)
                self.db = user;

            if(ready !== undefined)
                ready.call(this);
        });
}


new User(1, function() {
    console.log(this); // <- your users instance
});
```

V2: Otherwise you need an eventqueue on user (producer consumer pattern) which gets dispatched after everything is instantiated fine.

V3: Use JQuery events, then call $.when method to collect multiple callbacks.

v4: Write your own callback queue to sync your callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd use a Promise

```
var when = require('when');
function User(id) {
    var d = when.defer();
    this.ready = d.promise;

    var self = this;
    if (id)
        UserDB.findById(id, function(err, user) { // async
            if (!err && user){
                self.db = user;
                d.resolve();
}       }); }

user = new User('53179fd401d540b8c5000001');
user.ready.then(function(){
    console.log(user.db.id);
});
```